# Edit Buddypress Groups Activity Page Text

Tags: plugins, php, buddypress

I am setting up a Wordpress site with Buddypress functionality for a client. The client wants the "What's new" text under the "Activity" tab changed to something else. I feel like this should be editable in the Buddypress theme files, but I can't seem to find it.

Here's a screenshot with the text I'm talking about:

http://screencast.com/t/WsUdoycKro

Anyone know which file generates this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't edit that file.

You should over-ride it.

Create a folder called 'buddypress' in the root of your theme folder. 
Place a copy of post-form.php in that folder - using the same dir structure as 
bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/

Then you can update buddypress without losing your changes.

Comment: "using the same dir structure" So if I'm using the theme 'twentysixteen', and BuddyPress has post-form.php in activity/ then I should copy post-form.php to `twentysixteen/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/activity/`?  Or just `twentysixteen/buddypress/activity/`?

Comment: twentysixteen/buddypress/activity/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out myself. I kept trying to edit buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/activity/post-form.php when I need to edit bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/activity/post-form.php.

The lines I edited were 23 and 25:

```
<p class="activity-greeting"><?php if ( bp_is_group() )
        printf( __( "Write a message to %s, %s?", 'buddypress' ), bp_get_group_name(), bp_get_user_firstname() );
    else
        printf( __( "Write a message to %s?", 'buddypress' ), bp_get_user_firstname() );
    ?></p>
```

s